# fs.write() in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-io, fs

i am writing a code in which i have to create files equal to number of elements in a array and write respective array element in files.
for example array = [one,two,three], then i want to have file one with content one and so on.

```
var inputLength = inputs.length;

inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
    i = inputs.indexOf(elem);
    console.log(i);
    fs.writeFile(Execute.path + Execute.folder + "/inputFile" + i, elem, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Input" + i + " file was saved!");
        }

    });


    console.log(i);


});
```

output of first `console.log(i)` is fine i.e. 0,1,2,3 so on but output of second `console.log(i)` is always the index of last element.

whats the problem in my code and how to achieve my goal

Comment: use fs.writeFileSync if you want to write in a loop and do it in synchronous manner.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the loops but [`fs.writeFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) is an asynchronous call, so you need to use IIFE / Closure for this:

```
var inputLength = inputs.length;

inputs.forEach(function(elem) {
  i = inputs.indexOf(elem);
  (function (i) {
    console.log(i);
    fs.writeFile(Execute.path + Execute.folder + "/inputFile" + i, elem, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("Input" + i + " file was saved!");
      }
    });
    console.log(i);
  })(i);
});
```

The other way of doing the same is to use a synchronous counterpart: [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options).

Comment: after implementing your code i got a error
`/home/mritunjay/code-compiler/execute_code.js:77
                    })(i);
                      ^

TypeError: inputs.forEach(...) is not a function`

Comment: @ClubFlux LoL. No way... That can't happen... Immediately revert back to your original code and check? Even that should throw this error. `:P`